# yii2: registerJs in view which is rendered without layout

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Simple question, I think. Sometimes I render views without layout to produce code for popup div for example. If I need to associate js with this div, I usually store it in the same file, so js is loaded when needed with view and you don't need to store all js in one file. How to do it with yii2? As I can see, registerJs, registerJsFile here don't work, because view is rendered without layout. Thank you in advance!

Comment: try simply adding your js file (via `<script-...>`)  without register...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspite of it You can use 
`renderAjax("view")`;

in your controller ..where you want to show pop - up read [Render Ajax](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#renderAjax%28%29-detail)

Where in View you can use registerJs()  without including in your Seprate JS File

Answer (score 0):

Import in your view, another view with the script code with:

```
<?= $this->render('../views/script') ?>
```